# How do I turn off Sourcery's buttons above every class/funtion in VSCode?

Tags: vscode-extensions

How do I make VSCode not put these buttons above every class and function declaration? It's getting in the way of my reading over the script.

It's started appearing within maybe the past week or so, but I'm not exactly sure.

[image: code snippet with Sourcery buttons]